# Run script on mount

Tags: mount, backup, systemd

I have an encrypted HDD for which I would like to run a backup script when it is mounted. I found some information on how to achieve this with upstart, but since Ubuntu 15.04 uses systemd this information is of no use for me.

I would be happy if someone could point me in the right direction on this matter.

Comment: Would run the script on log in work?

Comment: no, I only decrypt the device if I need the files

Comment: I see. what is tho mount point if mounted?

Comment: It is /media/username/Documents, but I guess I could change that if need be

Comment: Posted my answer, please let me know if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a simple solution using systemd. With `WantedBy` systemd provides an easy way to run things if some other service is started. I just put the service in `\lib\systemd\system\crypt-backup.service`. It is activated by `systemctl enable crypt-backup.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Run the backup script when /media/stephan/Documents gets mounted

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/media/stephan/Documents/backup.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=media-stephan-Documents.mount
```